# Vmrun runProgramInGuest failing in Debian 6 guest

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, debian-squeeze

I have a vmware guest in vmware workstation.
I can start or stop the VM using `vmrun` but `runProgramInGuest` and `runScriptInGuest` are failing with `invalid username or password in guest`, however the username and password are both valid. Vmware tools are installed in guest.

```
vmrun version: 1.10
vmware WS 7.0
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vmware tools try to use /lib/security/pam_unix2.so wich not exist. Creating a link from pam_unix.so it works.

```
ln /lib/security/pam_unix.so /lib/security/pam_unix2.so
```

Comment: In my case, I had to do `ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/security /lib/security`, but your post was what made me look more closely at the output of `strace -p $(pgrep vmtoolsd) -e open`. Thanks a lot, man!